# SQL query exlude data between date and also matching another condition

Tags: sql

All,

First time poster on here. I am trying to create a query where I want to exclude data between a date range but also having certain codes.

```
Date:

(substring(CAST(UTCBigintToUTCTime(starttime) as varchar(19)),0,11) not between '2012-05-08%' and '2012-05-10%
```

> Status Code:
>
> statuscode NOT IN ('58','59'))

What would my statement look like to exclude data that meets BOTH of those conditions? Everything I do excludes all in that date range and all in the status code range.

Thanks in advance. SQL newbie but learning :).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're over-thinking it a bit, and making it more complex than it needs to be.
And making it this complex, especially with negative logic, will also make it perform poorly.

How about something like:

```
select * from myTable where starttime < '2012-05-08' and starttime > '2012-05-10' and statuscode < 58 and statuscode > 59
```

Not sure what database you are using, or exactly what your data types are - adjust slightly as necessary, but try to stay away from nasty date/string conversions and 'NOT' conditions wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply GreyBeardedGeek but wont this exclude anything from 5/8 - 5/10? What I need is to still report on data from 5/8 and 5/10 but only is the statuscode in not 58 or 59. There are many other codes we have to still account for in that range. Basically the report I am creating is a failure report but I want to exclude that combination as it was due to some testing I was running that does not need to be reported on.

Comment: A little gotcha with the above approach: make sure you convert starttime to date (not datetime) before comparison. Otherwise it will include '2012-05-10 09:30:00' in the results as it's greater than '2012-05-10 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from myTable where convert(date,starttime) not between '2012-05-08' and '2012-05-10' and statuscode not in (58,59)
```

and let me know.